# Not able to update the tester name in a Test Set from vbscript

Tags: vbscript, alm

I am been trying to search online for a solution but due to lack of knowledge in HP ALM I am not able to search proper hit tags

```
  Set RunFactory = tsTest.RunFactory
  Set obj_theRun = RunFactory.AddItem(CStr(testrunname))
  obj_theRun.Status = sExecutionStatus '"Passed" '-- Status to be updated
  obj_theRun.Tester = strTesterName
```

**Getting error in this line object does not support obj_theRun.Tester**

I just want to update the Tester column(Not Responsible tester) in Test set via vbscript. Please refer to the attached image at the very last column (TesterAny help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: `obj_theRun` is of type `Run` (documented here: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/ota/Content/ota/topic8722.html ) which **does not** have a property named `Tester`.

Comment: So you mean, i cannot change the tester column from vbscript. If yes, whose and what object should i create. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for ALM says the Tester Name can be specified by passing an array as the argument to `AddItem`.

> https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/ota/Content/ota/topic8805.html?Highlight=tester
>
> An array consisting of the following elements:
>
> 1. Name - The name of the run (string. required).
> 2. Tester - The name of the user responsible (string. optional)
> 3. Location - The host name (string. optional). The default is the host name of the current machine

So change your code to this:

```
Set runFactory = tsTest.RunFactory

Dim newRunArgs(3)
newRunArgs(0) = testrunname ' `testrunname` is already a string so you don't need CStr.
newRunArgs(1) = "tester name goes here"
Set newRunArgs(2) = Nothing

Set newRun = RunFactory.AddItem( newRunArgs )
newRun.Status = sExecutionStatus '"Passed" '-- Status to be updated
```

Comment: Throwing error in `newRunArgs(2)`.  (Type Mismatch)

Comment: @nishitdey I've updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Object variable not set in the line `newRunArgs(2) = Nothing`

Comment: One last question how do i clear the `newRunArgs(3)`. Because in the second run it is getting failed.

Comment: @nishitdey I suggest you read VBScript's documentation so you truly understand what's going on instead of asking new questions for each small issue you encounter.